# Cordova - How to save and read JSON object from localstorage

Tags: javascript, json, sqlite, cordova, local-storage

I have a cordova project which makes a web service call. This results in a json object

```
Object {deletedIds: Array[0], ... etc etc
```

I am trying to save this to a database and then read the data if there is no internet connection present.

From the function that gets the data, I set the data into localStorage (`localStorage.setItem("folderData", data);`), then call `db.transaction(queryFolderTable, errorCB);`.

This then reads the localstorage, saves it (if possible) and reads it (if there is no internet connection)

When i come to select the data from the table, I call the querySuccessFolderData function

```
function querySuccessFolderData(tx, results) {
    var len = results.rows.length;
    alert("folderData table: " + len + " rows found.");
    for (var i=0; i<len; i++){
        var folderData = results.rows.item(i).folderData;
    }
    console.log(folderData);
}
```

When I console.log the folderData (or don't add JSON.parse to anything) I get the following:

```
[object Object]
```

How would I be able to successfully save the data as a json object, then read it out correctly? I have tried to JSON.parse the data before setting it in localStorage but I get the following console error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o
```

If i try to JSON.parse the data when I read it from localStorage I get the following 2 errors

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o connection.js:
Error processing SQL: 0
```

What am i doing wrong? Do I need to JSON.stringify the data to make it readable at any point? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, try to JSON.stringify object before save to the database. And when you read data => JSON.parse it to get object.

Comment: I have to add my object to localStorage first to use it in a different function. When I JSON.parse the data I get this error 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o'

Comment: If i add it to localStorage as an object then retrieve it, it shows up as "[object Object]" in the console.